# Is it possible to run a for loop within any Python solvers?

Tags: python, for-loop, solver

I am attempting to find a solution to a reliability engineering nonlinear problem with only a single unknown. This should be relatively easy; however, the problem I have come across is within the summation part of the equation. My research so far leads me to believe that it is not possible to run a for loop within a solver in Python.

The equation I am trying to solve is:
[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snEkC.jpg)

The equation considers the outcomes of a simple reliability test. Some of the equation variables are included within lists while others are single scalars. The equation variables are:

d = the "fix effectiveness factor", the fraction of a failure mode's failure rate that will be mitigated by corrective action

v = the time during the test that the corrective action was applied

n = the number of failures observed during the test for each failure mode

m = the total number of failure modes surfaced

T = the total test time (in this case 25 units tested for 175 hours = 4375 hours).

I am trying to solve the equation for beta_hat. I have used other methods/software to solve the equation and I know that beta_hat = 0.0016, however, I need to solve this equation using Python as that is what I used for all other code.

The lists holding the values for each equation element are:

```
d = [0.5, 0., 0., 0., 0.8, 0., 0.7, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0., 0.]
v = [4375., 0., 0., 0., 4375., 0., 4375., 2500., 4375., 4375., 4375., 0., 0.]
n = [1, 3, 16, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1]
m = 13
T = 4375
```

I have unsuccessfully tried to use scipy.optimize (fsolve, root, least_squares), but I'm starting to run out of ideas and I think the problem may be that I can't run a for loop in a solver in Python like this example:

```
def f(x):
    for i in range(m):
        ((1 + x * T) / (x**2 * T)) * math.log(1 + x * T) * np.sum(n[i] / (1 / x + v[i] + (1 - d[i]) * (T - v[i]))) - m
    return f

result = optimize.root(f, 0.01)
print(result)
```

Any suggestions/ideas on how I might tackle this problem? Could there be a way I'm missing to run the for loop outside of the solver?

Comment: I don't understand. Your `for` loop really doesn't accomplish anything: it does a lot of computation, but throws away all the results.  Your function returns `f`, which is useless for the solver:  the solver needs it to return a number, not a function.  Whatever solver you use has no idea whether the function you pass to it runs a `for` loop, so that's _not_ the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, your `f()` doesn't compute a number for the solver to use.  Nor does it appear to implement the equation you linked to.  Here's a complete program, including a made-up toy solver:

```
def bisect(f, lo, hi, numiters):
    assert f(lo) < 0.0
    assert f(hi) > 0.0
    for _ in range(numiters):
        mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2.0
        y = f(mid)
        if y < 0.0:
            lo = mid
        else:
            hi = mid
    return lo

d = [0.5, 0., 0., 0., 0.8, 0., 0.7, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0., 0.]
v = [4375., 0., 0., 0., 4375., 0., 4375., 2500., 4375., 4375., 4375., 0., 0.]
n = [1, 3, 16, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1]
m = 13
T = 4375

def f(x):
    from math import log
    s = 0.0
    for i in range(m):
        s += n[i] / (1.0 / x + v[i] + (1.0 - d[i]) * (T - v[i]))
    return s * ((1.0 + x * T) / (x**2 * T)) * log(1.0 + x * T) - m
```

Given that:

```
>>> f(5)
-12.979641343531911
>>> f(0.001)
3.975686546173577
>>> bisect(f, 5, 0.001, 53)
0.0016334432920776716
```

which appears to match the 0.0016 you expect the answer to be.

So think about all that: the problem almost certainly isn't in the solvers you're trying to use, but in the function you're passing to them.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I appreciate your response. After reviewing my original efforts I understand now what I was doing wrong. After a bit of playing around, I have managed to get the correct answer using both fsolve and root. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Given Tim's comments and feedback, I modified my code and checked the answer using both solve and root. Both efforts delivered the same result (as expected).

```
from math import log
from scipy.optimize import solve, root

d = [0.5, 0., 0., 0., 0.8, 0., 0.7, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0., 0.]
v = [4375., 0., 0., 0., 4375., 0., 4375., 2500., 4375., 4375., 4375., 0., 0.]
n = [1, 3, 16, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1]
m = 13
T = 4375

def f(x):
    c = 0.0
    for i in range(m):
        c += n[i] / (1.0 / x + v[i] + (1.0 - d[i]) * (T - v[i]))
    return ((1.0 + x * T) / (x**2 * T)) * log(1.0 + x * T) * c - m
```

which results in

```
>>> fsolve(f, 0.001)
array([0.00163344])
>>> root(f, 0.001)
x: array([0.00163344])
```